# React project not shown in GitHub Pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I published my first React project on GitHub Pages. It is a covid 19 info tracker, but unfortunately I found it's not showing its content on page, it gives me a message " Edit src/App.js and save to reload".

My GitHub pages link: https://mosalem84.github.io/covid19dashboard/

and the repository link: https://github.com/MoSalem84/covid19dashboard

After I check my app.js again I find it looks empty. I don't know why. Is it possible GitHub removed my code lines from app.js?

Comment: Looks like you have deployed the React starter project and it doesn't have any changes. Hence the contents of vanilla App.js are being displayed. Not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: What makes you think that's *not* working?

Comment: @jonrsharpe simply because the project is about covid -19 info tracker, and it not appear any information in gh page !!

Comment: But that information isn't in any of the *code*, either. You only ever pushed one commit, three weeks ago, and the word COVID only appears in the package file: https://github.com/MoSalem84/covid19dashboard/commit/a56f03afdae7b788a844c6b7bbc1248ea85fdc8f

Comment: @AbhijayKumar hello , i think i not get your point correctly , i check my project locally and it working fine and appear data correctly but when deploy to gh page it gives my black page

Comment: @AbhijayKumar 

ok , i think i understand now after i check my app.js again i find it looks empty ! i don't know why ? also i found githup gives me message "We found potential security vulnerabilities in your dependencies." 
is it possible gh remove my code lines from app.js ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe

after i check my app.js again i find it looks empty ! i don't know why ? also i found githup gives me message "We found potential security vulnerabilities in your dependencies." 
is it possible gh remove my code lines from app.js ?

Comment: In all probability you just haven't committed and/or pushed your code, so what's on GitHub isn't what you have locally. But we can't tell from here, you need to give a [mre]. I'd recommend reading GitHub's tutorials too: https://guides.github.com/

Comment: @jonrsharpe
ok i really don't know what is wrong , app is working fine from my local machine as shown here 

https://i.ibb.co/2q8pf48/Capture.jpg

but when upload to gp it sitll gives me "Edit src/App.js and save to reload" i make sure i import all JS files into this App.js file 

can help please ? this is my first react project and i It took me a great time and effort , i study react and git and github by self study so please accept my little experience on it .

Comment: You've only pushed master. The gh-pages branch, which I assume is what your site is being served from, is still three weeks old: https://github.com/MoSalem84/covid19dashboard/commits/gh-pages. Looking at your package file I suspect you missed a `yarn deploy`.

Answer (score 1):

You have not pushed any of your local environment/editor changes to GitHub. As people have said, your last commit was 3 weeks ago.

You need to commit your code to **Git on your local system** and then **push these local changes to GitHub**.

Furthermore, you will also have to deploy/deploy your React app. This tells React to create the files needed to run on a production server. Here is the documentation to [publish the deployed app to GitHub](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages).

But don't forget to push your changes to the correct repo on your GitHub.

Good luck

Comment: thank you Alex , i currently check my code again and documents  you provide and i will let you know if it works .

Comment: ok i really don't know what is wrong , app is working fine from my local machine as shown here 

https://i.ibb.co/2q8pf48/Capture.jpg

but when upload to gp it sitll gives me "Edit src/App.js and save to reload" i make sure i import all JS files into this App.js file 

can help please ? this is my first react project and i It took me a great time and effort , i study react and git and github by self study so please accept my little experience on it .

Comment: You have pushed your source code to GitHub now, as your App.js says it updated 3 hours ago.

But your gh-pages branch has not been updated. You need to follow the tutorial I sent to build the react app from the source code. This will publish your compiled react app code to your gh-pages branch. That is what GitHub uses.

Because you have not done this, it is still displaying the default React app as this is automatically compiled when you run create-react-app. 

Once you have done that, push your code again, and make sure in settings that gh pages is still active. Then it should work!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL || ''}>

instead of BrowserRouter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).